# SSH keys can't be deleted from agent

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, ssh-agent

My Ubuntu 18.04 keeps adding all my SSH keys into the *ssh agent* upon startup and I am unable to delete them. Having so many keys in the agent breaks authentication to servers that only permit 3 or 5 attempts.

```
~ $ ssh-add -l
2048 SHA256:7mW8C9RNZ75U...ArHq+9kSZLmny0Y google_compute_engine (RSA)
2048 SHA256:OUD4Vy0LKWp2...AwNKTbdHDkjVkcU id_rsa.aws (RSA)
2048 SHA256:/Qbw+NcgXBTk...pi7bYs2eYm0k7B8 id_rsa.aws-eu (RSA)
2048 SHA256:cG5xEwfejo2O...8LqmP4gk2wAtzrk id_rsa (RSA)
2048 SHA256:5TgVaBUrlSvV...PHM46avPZIauVRY sftp-test2 (RSA)
```

When I try to delete them it says OK but they are still there:

```
~ $ ssh-add -D
All identities removed.

~ $ ssh-add -l
2048 SHA256:7mW8C9RNZ75U...ArHq+9kSZLmny0Y google_compute_engine (RSA)
2048 SHA256:OUD4Vy0LKWp2...AwNKTbdHDkjVkcU id_rsa.aws (RSA)
2048 SHA256:/Qbw+NcgXBTk...pi7bYs2eYm0k7B8 id_rsa.aws-eu (RSA)
2048 SHA256:cG5xEwfejo2O...8LqmP4gk2wAtzrk id_rsa (RSA)
2048 SHA256:5TgVaBUrlSvV...PHM46avPZIauVRY sftp-test2 (RSA)
```

With so many identities loaded in the agent I can't even specify an explicit on the command line, it still fails:

```
~ $ ssh 192.168.56.5  -i ~/.ssh/test
Received disconnect from 192.168.56.5 port 22:2: Too many authentication failures
Disconnected from 192.168.56.5 port 22
```

The only thing I can do is `unset SSH_AUTH_SOCK` altogether and then I can at least use `ssh -i ...` but that's inconvenient.

### TL;DR

How can I delete all the identities from the agent **and** prevent them from loading again next time? Ie how to make it behave like *ssh agent* used to?

Answer (score 8):

This may be due to a bug in `ssh-add -d/-D` *not removing* keys. There were some bug reports about it, e.g.

- [Debian Bug report #472477: ssh-add -D does not remove SSH key from
  gnome-keyring-daemon memory](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=472477)
- [Ubuntu: ssh-add -D deleting all identities does not work. Also, why
  are all identities auto-added?](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openssh/+bug/505278)

The exact issue is:

> `ssh-add -d/-D` deletes only manually added keys from gnome-keyring.
>   There is no way to delete automatically added keys. This is the
>   original bug, and it's still definitely present.
>
> Allowing `ssh-add -d` to apply to automatically-loaded keys (and `ssh-add -t X` to change the lifetime of automatically-loaded keys), would restore the behaviour most users expect.

A possible workaround:

> Do `ssh-add -D` to delete all your manually added keys.
>
> Navigate to your `~/.ssh` folder and move all your key files except the one you want to
>   identify with into a separate folder called backup. If necessary you
>   can also open seahorse and delete the keys from there.

Another workaround:

> What you really want to do is to turn off `gpg-keyring-daemon`
>   altogether. Go to `System --> Preferences --> Startup Applications`, and
>   unselect the "`SSH Key Agent (Gnome Keyring SSH Agent)`" box -- you'll
>   need to scroll down to find it.
>
> You'll still get an `ssh-agent`, only now it will behave sanely: no keys
>   autoloaded, you run `ssh-add` to add them, and if you want to delete
>   keys, you can.

[This comments](https://superuser.com/questions/281217/cant-remove-keys-from-ssh-agent-even-rebooting-doesnt-help#comment739325_301444) actually suggests:

> The solution is to `keep gnome-keyring-manager` from ever starting up,
>   which was strangely difficult by finally achieved by removing the
>   program file's execute permission.

Comment: I'd like to point out this bug report which suggests a couple of other solutions, Fedora among others: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1205558